# Alternativa ao sed com PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

No UNIX eu faria algo tipo assim: `sed -n '/início/,/fim/ p' < arquivo.txt`

No Windows nós temos o PowerShell, como é que se faz isso com ele?

Comment: vc quer ler um arquivo pegar o resultado da regex e jogar em um novo arquivo?

Comment: Por enquanto só visualizar.

Comment: Talvez nem todo mundo tenha entendido o significado do comando, talvez vc pudesse explicar melhor, imagino que seja possível traduzir para powershell.

Comment: @rray obrigado pelo apoio, eu mesmo já consegui veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127000/43845 , mas não sei porque deram down vote...

Comment: Talvez dê para simplificar esse código.

Comment: eu não sei muito sobre PS, to aprendendo mesmo é hoje, se você puder simplificar ele @rray

Comment: quando instalas a powershell no windows, obtens algo "parecido" com a bash do unix. Para lidar com expressões regulares do modo poderoso que tens em unix, convem juntar os utilitários correspondentes (sed, awk, grep, perl, cut, paste, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, aproveitei a ocasião para aprender um pouco de PS. Aqui está uma solução para o problema (a linguagem está em powershell).

```
#se der acesso não autorizado, execute "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser"

#$inclusive=$true mostra as linhas com os padrões.
#ao fazer essa função extrai a ideia do seguinte post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25639841/3697611
#sed $início, $fim, $inclusive
function sed {
    $mostrar = $false
    $início = $args[0]
    $fim = $args[1]
    $inclusive = $args[2]
    $input | %{ #pega entrada do pipeline https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx
        if ($_ -match $início) { 
            $mostrar = $true; if ($inclusive){echo $_} 
        } elseif ($_ -match $fim) { 
            $mostrar = $false; if ($inclusive){echo $_} 
        } elseif ($mostrar) {
            echo $_ 
        }
    }
}

#teste de unidade
function sedTest {
    ("início`nbloco`nfim".Split("`n")|
        sed "^início$" "^fim$" $false) -eq "bloco"
}

sedTest
```

Comment: Pessoal, fui eu mesmo que fiz a pergunta. Por que deram um voto negativo se foi a única postagem que foi colocado código em PowerShell? Deveriam dar votos negativos para respostas que não mostram código na linguagem requisitada.

Comment: *+1*. Dependendo do que você quer fazer da para usar o [`gc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx), nesse [*post*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2007/07/08/grep-and-sed-with-powershell/)  do *msdn* também mostra outras formas.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer:

```
(Get-Content arquivo.txt).replace('valorAtual','valorFuturo') | Set-Content arquivo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta curta**

Não faz, o shell do Unix/Linux é muito mais poderoso do que o do Windows.

**Resposta longa**

Por causa dessas coisas recentemente a Microsoft anunciou que colocará o bash como shell nativo do Windows em versões futuras.

Vc pode ainda usar as bibliotecas GNU compiladas para Windows:

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

entre elas está o SED que vc precisa.

Vc tbém pode usar o projeto Cygwin que é um port do ambiente *nix para windows

https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário, realmente os utilitários do unix/linux são muito práticos, dificilmente haveria um substituto a altura

Comment: Grato @JJoao, procuro fazer o melhor

Comment: O powershell atual está muito mais poderoso do que ele era na data da resposta.
Vale a pena estudar as suas capacidades de hoje.

Comment: @GabrielJefferson não valeu... drogas não são minha vibe :P :D

Answer (score 1):

Já agora, o **Strawberry-Perl** para windows vem com alguns utilitários
(gcc, compile tools, bibliotecas, interface a bases de dados, etc).

Fornece um ambiente de desenvolvimento parecido com o perl de unix.

seguidamente um exemplo análogo ao teu sed:

```
perl -0nE 'say for(/inicio.*?fim/gs)' arquivo.txt
```

Comment: Interessante amigo, já há muito tempo brinquei com perl no linux. No entanto João, gostaria de exemplos na linguagem requisitada, PowerShell.

Comment: depois de instalado o strawberry, em principio, esta linha corre em todas as shells (powershell, cmd, na shell que o perl instala )

Comment: obrigado por tentar ajudar @JJoao.

Comment: meu amigo @JJoao voltei a aprender perl esses dias e vi como é prático essa linguagem! rs